# Which ternary operator in C# is most popular and mostly used?

Tags: c#, ternary-operator, ternary

Which ternary operator in C# is most popular and mostly used?

Comment: Edited, but I have no real idea what he meant.

Comment: The most popular ternary oparator in C# has to be the conditional operator, as that is the only ternary operator...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The operator sometimes known as the ternary operator is actually named the *conditional operator*. It's of the form

```
A ? B : C
```

where A is a Boolean expression, and B and C are expressions either of the same type, or of types such that the type of B can be implicitly converted to the type of C or vice versa.

First A is evaluated; if the result is `true` then B is evaluated to provide the result. Otherwise C is evaluated to provide the result.

Comment: When did you change your name?

Comment: Only you can get 7 upvotes in one minute on what was originally an incomprehensible question. ;)

Comment: At least, you have left the "why is popular" part unanswered to give the rest of us an opportunity :-)

Comment: @DrG: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28192/has-jon-skeet-been-hacked/28194#28194

Answer (score 4):

It is popular because it leads to shorter and more readable code. Consider this simple example:

```
int daysInYear = isLeapYear ? 366 : 365;
```

instead of

```
if(isLeapYear) {
   daysInYear = 366;
} else {
   daysInYear = 365;
}
```